# How to pass an Id for a raw query in the model, which does not have primary key?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have my model defined as follows (**ps**: no primary key for the view I use in this model class, is: **vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite**)

```
class Alarm extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite';
    public $timestamps  = false ;

    public function scopeActiveAlarms($query)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('AlarmClearedUTCDateTime', '=', '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'); 
    }

    public function alarmActionDescription()
    {
        $rec = \DB::table('vwAlarmActionSummary')
            ->where('AlarmId', '=', $this->AlarmId);

        return $rec;
    }

}
```

Im calling above model like;

```
 $alarm = Alarm::where('AlarmId', $id)->where('yfUserID', $yfUserID)->firstOrFail();
```

Now Im getting this exception at  `alarmActionDescription()` method;

```
(1/2) LogicException
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
in HasAttributes.php (line 403)
at Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('AlarmActionDescription')
in HasAttributes.php (line 386)
at Model->getRelationValue('AlarmActionDescription')
in HasAttributes.php (line 316)
```

I want to return a row from `vwAlarmActionSummary` table, for that i'm passing `AlarmId`, which is passed as `$id` from my controller.

What is wrong here? How can I modify my `alarmActionDescription()` method to return a row based on `AlarmId` ?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're using the alarmActionDescription()

Comment: @Wreigh, Im calling my model as I pointed in my question like $alarm = Alarm::where('AlarmId', $id)->where('yfUserID', $yfUserID)->firstOrFail(); I expect that $alarm should return a row which contains information from alarmActionDescription() method

Comment: Yes, where and how are you calling the method `alarmActionDescription()` ?

Comment: @Wreigh im not explicitly calling in any php code. But in my Views I try access prperties of $alarm object like; <div class="col-md-6 control-label-text-left">{{ $alarm->AlarmActionDescription}}</div>

Comment: see my answer. If you have any questions, just comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're calling the method `alarmActionDescription()` wrongly.

Like this:

```
$alarm->alarmActionDescription;
```

Calling it like that makes it an attribute. Doing that, Laravel assumes that you're trying to get a list of relations. For example in your alarm you have:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

If you do:

```
$alarm->users;
```

You will receive a collection of users related to your alarm.

Notice that you're calling an **attribute** with the same name as the **function** that we've declared a while ago.

But if you do:

```
$alarm->users();
```

It will perform the function and will return a relation, that is, `belongsToMany()`.

In your case however, the function `alarmActionDescription()`, you're not returning a **Relation**, you're returning a **row** from the Database.

What you may do is, call the method like:

```
$alarm->alarmActionDescription();
```

As opposed to what you've said you're doing:

```
$alarm->alarmActionDescription;
```

Notice the differences.

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships